# How to connect an external sensor to Zynq-7000 module?

Tags: simulink, xilinx, zynq

I'm currently working on a project to be implemented on a Xilinx Zedboard, using Simulink Embedded Coder methodology.

i need to interface an analog sensor (Electret Microphone) with the Zynq,i know that the XADC need to be instanciated in the PL then linked to the PS with the AXI, the DATA will be in the SDRAM that i need in my algorithm, but i don't know how to do it actually.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sami, there are many things you have to do. Instantiation of XADC is the first one. Then, you need to instantiate DMA and connect it properly in the FPGA part. Then, you have to write driver for DMA initialization. These isues are described (but not solved anyway) also e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037949/what-is-a-good-interface-for-a-linux-device-driver-for-a-co-processing-periphera/30078241#30078241). After these steps you can use Simulink Embedded Coder methodology.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Check at the PDF with the link, section: 2.5.1 I/O Peripheral (IOP) Interface Routing

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf

Good luck.

Comment: When you answer to a question by a link, please also summarize all relevants advices. Remember a link can expire soon after you provide it.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the response, but my method is completely different, i want to  implement it on a Xilinx Zedboard, using Simulink Embedded Coder methodology.

like in this tuto http://www.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/examples/getting-started-with-axi4-stream-interface-in-zynq-workflow.html

but i don't know how to work with the external port ( the sensor )